# Cannot get Captcha Widget to work on Electron HTML page

Tags: javascript, electron, cors, captcha

I am currently trying to get a Captcha to show up on a simple html page served by an electron app. I am using hCaptcha for this and followed the simple tutorial to implement the widget. (https://docs.hcaptcha.com/).

However when I open the webpage I get the CORS error :
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://hcaptcha.com/checksiteconfig?host=&sitekey=**********&sc=1&swa=1' from origin 'https://assets.hcaptcha.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I am a beginner in everything web related, I understand that this has something to do with cross domain resource security but I do not understand what the issue at hand is.

I added the relevant script

```
<script src="https://hcaptcha.com/1/api.js" async defer></script>
```

in the header and the div in my body

```
<div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="*********"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So for anyone wondering what the issue is, hCaptcha does not allow requests from urls which use the File:// protocol as well as the localhost url or localhost ip. To be able to get a captcha to show the page has to be hosted on a different url. This can be achieved locally with an edit for 127.0.0.1 in the computers host file, or when the page is ran on a proper server.